# Unable to get output from netconsole

Tags: linux, kernel, netcat, kernel-panic

nc -l -u 6666 on the receiving machine gets no messages from netconsole.

tested by doing "echo test > /dev/kmsg"

i am able to connect with netcat by doing "nc -u 10.0.0.192 6666" on the netconsole machine

"sudo tcpdump -i wlp170s0 -n -e port 6666" outputs nothing on the listening machine

netconsole options:

```
modprobe netconsole netconsole=6666@10.0.0.42/enp8s0,6666@10.0.0.192/54:14:f3:52:82:94 oops_only=0
```

ifconfig on netconsole machine:

```
enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:85:C2:D7:65:F3
          inet addr:10.0.0.42  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1032 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:95338  TX bytes:230456

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0  TX bytes:0
```

ifconfig on listening machine:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46289  TX bytes:46289

nfs       Link encap:(hwtype unknown)
          inet addr:10.8.0.3  P-t-P:10.8.0.3  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1420  Metric:1
          RX packets:7418 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22098 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1806372  TX bytes:26188072

wlp170s0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:14:F3:52:82:94
          inet addr:10.0.0.192  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2771549 errors:0 dropped:54 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1029444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3024953926  TX bytes:153598327
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you have to increase the verbosity with dmesg -n 8